# Share Authentication Headers from iPhone to Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, wcsession

Users log in on their iPhone into our app.
After that we securely store the authentication information in the keychain. Our users don't have to sign in each and every time they use the app.

Now we are adding a Watch app. We would like to do some network requests on the Watch as well. Would be lovely if this would work when the user is logged in on their phone.

However, Keychain Sharing cannot be done between the iOS and the Watch device. This could be done in the beginning of WatchOS but no more since WatchOS 2. So this leaves us with a problem.

So: We could send over data using `WCSession`.

but:

- How safe is that? Any ideas on how to make this safe?
- Are there other ways safely transfer authentication tokens from the Phone to the Watch?

Comment: I found a similar question, the answer may help you - it is safe!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35561033/4542810

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use updateApplicationContext to send keychain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073236/is-it-safe-to-use-updateapplicationcontext-to-send-keychain-value)